# Effective Chebotarev Density

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, effective-results

Let $K$ be a number field, and $p$ be a rational prime. Then the Chebotarev Density Theorem implies we can find primes $v$ and $w$ of $K$ of degree 1 which are split and nonsplit respectively in $K[\sqrt{p}]$. What is the best known effective (upper) bound for the norms of the least such primes (not assuming GRH)? In particular, is there a bound which is asymptotically strictly less than $\sqrt{p}$ (times a constant coming from the field $K$)?

EDIT: I'd like to clarify, in response to the comments below. The situation I'm wondering about is when we fix K, and let p vary. So when K is a cyclotomic field (adjoin, say, the qth root of unity for a prime q), I'm asking about the least prime which is a quadratic nonresidue (resp. residue) mod p, which is 1 mod some fixed prime q, and I'm hoping that there is a bound of the form $\sqrt{p}$ times (something in terms of q). Under GRH this is true --- in fact under GRH, we can get a bound of the shape $(\log p)^2$ times constants coming from K.

Comment: (Prompted by the comments in GH's answer) Do you really want $\sqrt p$, not square root of discriminant? See edit to my answer.

Comment: See my edit above to the question which addresses your example below.

Comment: I still think that $\sqrt{p}$ is pretty hopeless with present day technology, but at least for $K$ abelian I see room for improving upon what I wrote originally. For example, if $q>1$ is fixed and you are looking for an $\ell$ which is $1$ mod $q$ and of a given quadratic character mod $p$, then Linnik's theorem (see Wikipedia) guarantees $\ell\ll p^c$ with some constant $c$ (the current record is $c=5.2$). Linnik's theorem is pretty deep though, and the way I applied it is rather dull.

Answer (score 11):

I assume $\sqrt{p}$ is not contained in $K$, then the bound you are looking for is available.

Let $\chi$ be the ray class character attached to the quadratic extension $K(\sqrt{p})/K$, then the $L$-function $L(s,\chi)$ has conductor essentially $p$. By a recent result of Venkatesh (Theorem 6.1 in Annals of Math. 172 (2010), 989-1094) we have the subconvex bound $L(s,\chi)\ll |s|^N p^{1/4-1/200}$ on the criticial line $\Re s=1/2$, where $N>0$ is a constant. It follows, by a simple Mellin transformation technique, that for any fixed smooth function $V:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{C}$ of compact support we have

$$\sum_{\mathfrak{m}\subset\mathcal{O}_K}\chi(\mathfrak{m})V(N\mathfrak{m}/X)\ll p^{1/4-1/200} X^{1/2}.$$

Therefore the absolute value of the left hand side is smaller than $X$ for some $X\gg p^{1/2-1/100}$, where the implied constant depends only on $K$ and $V$. This implies that $\chi$ takes both values $\pm 1$ on prime ideals with norm $\ll p^{1/2-1/100}$.

Perhaps one can complement this with Vinogradov's trick, see Corollary 9.19 in Montgomery-Vaughan: Multiplicative number theory I.

EDIT: As the OP pointed out, all the $p$'s above should be replaced by $p^{(K:\mathbb{Q})}$.

Comment: I'm looking at Venkatesh's Theorem 6.1, and it looks like this gives a bound of $p^{(1/2 - 1/100) n}$, where $n$ is the degree of $K$, as opposed to $p^{1/2 - 1/100}$. Hopefully, I'm misunderstanding either your argument above or the statement of the theorem. But it looks like the bound depends on the norm (from K to Q) of the conductor, which would be $p^n$, as opposed to $p$?

Comment: Eric, I am afraid you are right. My $p$ is really the norm of the relative discriminant of the field extension which, as you say, is $p^n$ instead of $p$. I'd think that in this case $p^{n/2}$ is the natural "easy" bound for the norms of your $v$ and $w$, not $p^{1/2}$. This is certainly the case for the sum in my response which is a natural analytic device to study your question. The number you can put in front of $X^{1/2}$ on the right is really the quantity that Venkatesh studied in part of his paper. So personally I'd be surprised if my response did not contain the state of the art.

Answer (score 9):

The paper:

J. C. Lagarias, H. L. Montgomery and A. M. Odlyzko, A bound for the least prime ideal in the Chebotarev density theorem, Invent. Math. 54 (1979) 271-296

gives a bound of the form $c \sqrt p$ for some unspecified $c$.

My paper with J. Vaaler:

The least nonsplit prime in Galois extensions of Q, J. Number Theory, 85 (2000), 320-335.

gives an effective constant (when $K=\mathbb Q$, but the argument should generalize). Actually, the quadratic field case of our argument is already in Gauss. Our paper has a bunch of other references, including what you can get with GRH. Improving the square root bound without GRH is a big open problem.

The paper also gives me Erdos number 2 :-)

EDIT: As in GH's answer, the natural quantity for the bounds is the discriminant, so $p$ needs to be replaced by $p^n, n=[K:\mathbb Q]$, in the case of $K(\sqrt p)$. Here is an example where this will make a big difference. Take $K$ to be the cyclotomic field of $p$-th roots of unity where $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$, so the quadratic extension is non trivial. The OP asks for degree one primes, these are primes above rational primes $l \equiv 1 \mod p$, so they have norm $l > p$ and you can't expect a $\sqrt p$ bound.

Comment: The square root bound has been improved (for abelian extensions), see my response sent a minute ago.

Comment: @GH: Thanks. Your comment also reminded me of this recent paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.5718 which has improvements for extensions of degree at least three.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! I keep collecting arxiv preprints, but I am always behind with naming and looking at them properly. So although I had Li's paper on my hard disk, I was not really aware of it. BTW I edited some exponents in my original response.