# Is there always, for a given prime $p$, a prime $\ell<p$ that is not a quadratic residue mod $p$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

The question is in the title, and I do not really have anything to add. Nevertheless I had to write something here in order to be able to ask the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Of course. Take a quadratic nonresidue $1\leq n\leq p-1$, then some prime divisor $\ell$ of $n$ will be a quadratic nonresidue.

See [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52211/effective-chebotarev-density/52237#52237) for what is known about number fields.

Comment: Come on. There is this story about Grothendieck. He lectured like "take a prime $p$". Then someone asked from the audience: can $p$ be an arbitrary prime? He responded, sure, like $57$.

Comment: :-)           .

Comment: That puts me in great company!  When I was an undergraduate, I had a habit of factoring numbers that I saw as I walked around.  When I passed room 57, I thought to myself "That's interesting, 57 is prime *and* divisible by 3!"

Comment: @Jeff: LOL. I am not sure Grothendieck went to such depths though.

Answer (score 10):

It is actually quite easy to prove that if $p>3$, then there are at least $2$ primes less than $p$ which are quadratic non-residues. Indeed, assume there were only one, say $q$. Then every $n$ between $1$ and $p-1$ which is not multiple of $q$ is a quadratic residue. Since you have at most $(p-1)/q$ multiples of $q$, and exactly $(p-1)/2$ quadratic residues, this implies $q=2$ and moreover $p=3$ (since otherwise you would get too many quadratic residues: every odd number between $1$ and $p-1$, together with $4$).

Comment: Nice          . 

Comment: I wonder what lower bound can we prove for the number of quadratic nonresidue primes $1\leq\ell\leq p-1$. For the number of quadratic residue primes $1\leq\ell\leq p-1$ I can prove $\gg\log p/\log\log p$ by an elementary argument involving quadratic reciprocity.

Comment: I made my previous comment into an official MO question. I hope it survives.

Comment: Well, it survived!

Answer (score 7):

Slightly different in emphasis, the smallest quadratic nonresidue is in fact prime, as the product of residues is another residue.

Answer (score 2):

Erdos conjectured that for any sufficiently large prime $p$ there is a primitive root $q<p$ for $p$ which is prime.

Comment: That's interesting, I haven't heard about this!

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is obvious. Since
$$\sum_{1\leq n\leq p-1}\left(\frac{n}{p}\right)=0$$, there must exist a positive integer $n\leq p-1$, such that $(\frac{n}{p})=-1$, or else the summation above must be equal to $p-1$. Of course, maybe $n$ is not a prime, however there always be a prime factor $\ell$ of $n$ such that $(\frac{\ell}{p})=-1$.

Comment: This answer is the same as GH's, only using an unnecessarily complicated argument as to why there is a quadratic nonresidue $1\leq n\leq p-1$.