# Effective Chebotarev density results for arbitrary number fields 

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

So let $f(x)\in\mathbf{Z}[x]$ be a monic polynomial of degree $d$ and let $K$ be the splitting field of $f$. Let us define 
the "heigt of $f$" $:=||f||$ to be the maximum of the abolute values of 
the coefficients of $f$. (Instead of the height it might be better to work with the abolute value of the discriminant of $K$).

Let us denote the Galois group of $f$ over $\mathbf{Q}$ by
$G$. For each prime number for which the roots of $f$ modulo $p$ are distinct we denote by
$G_p$ the Galois group of $f\pmod{p}$. A cute result that may be found for example in Van der Waerden first algebra book says that there exists an (non-canonical but well defined up to conjugation in  $G$) injection of $G_p$ in $G$. By elementary group theory, if we take the group generated by a set of representatives of the conjugacy classes of $G$ then it generates $G$. Thus by Chebotarev density theorem, we know that there exists a finite set of prime numbers 
$S$ of $\mathbf{Q}$ such that
$$
G_S:=\langle G_p| p\in S\rangle=G.
$$
In particular, we may always choose a set $S$ with $G_S=G$  and 
$|S|\leq r$ where $r$ is the number of conjugacy classes of $G$.

**Q**: So let $S_x$ be the set of all prime numbers less than $x$. Is it possible to find explicitly a lower bound for $x$ in terms $||f||$ (or $|disc(K)|$) and $d$ such that 
$$
G_{S_x}=G?
$$

**added**: So basically, I'm just asking for an effective version of the Chebotarev density theorem for the splitting field of $f$, this is probably well known to the expert.
So probably one should consider $|disc(K)|$ rather than $||f||$ which can be arbitrary large for a fixed $K$ (even though $f$ may have bad reduction for many primes $p$ which do not divide $|disc(K)|$)

Comment: I removed some of the tags which seemed unnecessary to me.

Comment: Have you seen http://mathoverflow.net/questions/52211/effective-chebotarev-density ?

Comment: Five. One to hold the light bulb, four to turn the ladder. $$ $$
I was able to hold off for an hour from posting this, but sometimes one must give in to temptation.

Comment: Hi @Will, well my Q1 was kind of stupid. I realized it. If you take one representative in $G$ for every conjugacy class then it generates $G$, so this gives some easy lower bound. In any case, thanks for your comment.

Comment: I am about as far from being an expert as is possible.  So please excuse what might be a trivial comment.  But it seems that if for each prime you only know that there exists a non-canonical injection $G_p \to G$, then even knowing a bunch of $G_p$s by no means is enough to determine the group $G$.  Ok, fine, but it's worse: it seems perfectly possible that depending on the choice of injections $G_p \to G$, the set of necessary $p$s can vary vastly.  Now, maybe there's more structure that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Hi Theo, well the injection is well defined up to conjugation, thanks for your comment.

Comment: Hugo, I hope the question works out well for you. I was not so much indicating any judgment about your question as reporting that which popped into my head the instant I saw your title. I try not to do this too often. I waited over a year before finally indicating my gut response to questions that ask about names of things, and I did that on an MSE question: $$ $$
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46216/name-of-this-convex-polyhedron 
$$  $$
Anyway, good luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for the very useful paper

Effective versions of the Chebotarev density theorem, J. C. Lagarias and A. M. Odlyzko, pp. 409-464 in Algebraic Number Fields, A. Frohlich (ed.), Academic Press, 1977.

The bounds there are quite large, as I recall, especially if you don't want to assume GRH.  There is very nice recent work of Jouve, Kowalski, and Zywina that give a lot of insight into how to do this in practice and how many prime numbers you shoudl *expect* to have to use:  see [Kowalski's blog post about this](http://blogs.ethz.ch/kowalski/2008/07/24/the-chebotarev-invariant-or-wait-and-see/) and work cited there.

Comment: Could you please send me the paper by Lagarias and Odlyzko ? My email id is npur.suman@gmail.com.